# Degree and Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt{-3})/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$.

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

I would like to find the degree and Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt{-3})/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$.

I usually can compute the degree of an extension over $\mathbb{Q}$ as one only needs to find the minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ which is relatively easy to compute. On the other hand, whenever I have had to compute the minimal polynomial over some other extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ (for example, $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_i,\sqrt{2})/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$), the calculation has still been easy as it is an imaginary field over a real field. However, in the example I have proposed above, I do not seem to be able to proceed with the extension being real but base field being imaginary. Surely, $x^3-2$ is one of the polynomials, but how do I know if its the minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$?

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes, you are right I am so sorry, I messed up the question. I fixed it!

Comment: Yes, I got it! Thank you so so much @AnneBauval!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the degree of the polynomial $x^3-2$ is $3,$
to prove that it
is irreducible over $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-3}),$
you only need to check that $∀y∈\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-3}),y^3≠2.$
Write $y=a+b\sqrt{-3}$
with $a,b∈\Bbb Q$
and solve.

Now, this proves that the degree of the extension is $3.$
To derive the Galois group, check that your extension is normal. Hint: the *three* cubic roots of $1$
belong to $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-3}).$